# Sequelize "Connection closed" on Azure SQL

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, azure-sql-database

I have a Node v10.17.0 app on Ubuntu 16.04 using Sequelize 4.41.1 calling Azure SQL.

On every start up, the node app runs sync on each database model for any migrations. Sequelize sends queries to the database `IF OBJECT_ID('[Shop]', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE [Client] ...` etc to create the tables if they don't exist. Then `EXEC sys.sp_helpindex @objname = N''[Shop]`. The first couple of tables sync successfully (there aren't any changes).

Then we get to the query that returns the error `SequelizeDatabaseError message":"Connection closed before request completed." "code":"ECLOSE"`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[Client]', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE [Client] ([id] NVARCHAR(255) , [name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, [timezone] VARCHAR(255) CHECK ([timezone] IN(N'Africa/Abidjan', N'Africa/Accra', N'Africa/Addis_Ababa', N'Africa/Algiers', N'Africa/Asmara', N'Africa/Asmera', N'Africa/Bamako', N'Africa/Bangui', N'Africa/Banjul', N'Africa/Bissau', N'Africa/Blantyre', N'Africa/Brazzaville', N'Africa/Bujumbura', N'Africa/Cairo', N'Africa/Casablanca', N'Africa/Ceuta', N'Africa/Conakry', N'Africa/Dakar', N'Africa/Dar_es_Salaam', N'Africa/Djibouti', N'Africa/Douala', N'Africa/El_Aaiun', N'Africa/Freetown', N'Africa/Gaborone', N'Africa/Harare', N'Africa/Johannesburg', N'Africa/Juba', N'Africa/Kampala', N'Africa/Khartoum', N'Africa/Kigali', N'Africa/Kinshasa', N'Africa/Lagos', N'Africa/Libreville', N'Africa/Lome', N'Africa/Luanda', N'Africa/Lubumbashi', N'Africa/Lusaka', N'Africa/Malabo', N'Africa/Maputo', N'Africa/Maseru', N'Africa/Mbabane', N'Africa/Mogadishu', N'Africa/Monrovia', N'Africa/Nairobi', N'Africa/Ndjamena', N'Africa/Niamey', N'Africa/Nouakchott', N'Africa/Ouagadougou', N'Africa/Porto-Novo', N'Africa/Sao_Tome', N'Africa/Timbuktu', N'Africa/Tripoli', N'Africa/Tunis', N'Africa/Windhoek', N'America/Adak', N'America/Anchorage', N'America/Anguilla', N'America/Antigua', N'America/Araguaina', N'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires', N'America/Argentina/Catamarca', N'America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia', N'America/Argentina/Cordoba', N'America/Argentina/Jujuy', N'America/Argentina/La_Rioja', N'America/Argentina/Mendoza', N'America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos', N'America/Argentina/Salta', N'America/Argentina/San_Juan', N'America/Argentina/San_Luis', N'America/Argentina/Tucuman', N'America/Argentina/Ushuaia', N'America/Aruba', N'America/Asuncion', N'America/Atikokan', N'America/Atka', N'America/Bahia', N'America/Bahia_Banderas', N'America/Barbados', N'America/Belem', N'America/Belize', N'America/Blanc-Sablon', N'America/Boa_Vista', N'America/Bogota', N'America/Boise', N'America/Buenos_Aires', N'America/Cambridge_Bay', N'America/Campo_Grande', N'America/Cancun', N'America/Caracas', N'America/Catamarca', N'America/Cayenne', N'America/Cayman', N'America/Chicago', N'America/Chihuahua', N'America/Coral_Harbour', N'America/Cordoba', N'America/Costa_Rica', N'America/Creston', N'America/Cuiaba', N'America/Curacao', N'America/Danmarkshavn', N'America/Dawson', N'America/Dawson_Creek', N'America/Denver', N'America/Detroit', N'America/Dominica', N'America/Edmonton', N'America/Eirunepe', N'America/El_Salvador', N'America/Ensenada', N'America/Fort_Nelson', N'America/Fort_Wayne', N'America/Fortaleza', N'America/Glace_Bay', N'America/Godthab', N'America/Goose_Bay', N'America/Grand_Turk', N'America/Grenada', N'America/Guadeloupe', N'America/Guatemala', N'America/Guayaquil', N'America/Guyana', N'America/Halifax', N'America/Havana', N'America/Hermosillo', N'America/Indiana/Indianapolis', N'America/Indiana/Knox', N'America/Indiana/Marengo', N'America/Indiana/Petersburg', N'America/Indiana/Tell_City', N'America/Indiana/Vevay', N'America/Indiana/Vincennes', N'America/Indiana/Winamac', N'America/Indianapolis', N'America/Inuvik', N'America/Iqaluit', N'America/Jamaica', N'America/Jujuy', N'America/Juneau', N'America/Kentucky/Louisville', N'America/Kentucky/Monticello', N'America/Knox_IN', N'America/Kralendijk', N'America/La_Paz', N'America/Lima', N'America/Los_Angeles', N'America/Louisville', N'America/Lower_Princes', N'America/Maceio', N'America/Managua', N'America/Manaus', N'America/Marigot', N'America/Martinique', N'America/Matamoros', N'America/Mazatlan', N'America/Mendoza', N'America/Menominee', N'America/Merida', N'America/Metlakatla', N'America/Mexico_City', N'America/Miquelon', N'America/Moncton', N'America/Monterrey', N'America/Montevideo', N'America/Montreal', N'America/Montserrat', N'America/Nassau', N'America/New_York', N'America/Nipigon', N'America/Nome', N'America/Noronha', N'America/North_Dakota/Beulah', N'America/North_Dakota/Center', N'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem', N'America/Ojinaga', N'America/Panama', N'America/Pangnirtung', N'America/Paramaribo', N'America/Phoenix', N'America/Port-au-Prince', N'America/Port_of_Spain', N'America/Porto_Acre', N'America/Porto_Velho', N'America/Puerto_Rico', N'America/Punta_Arenas', N'America/Rainy_River', N'America/Rankin_Inlet', N'America/Recife', N'America/Regina', N'America/Resolute', N'America/Rio_Branco', N'America/Rosario', N'America/Santa_Isabel', N'America/Santarem', N'America/Santiago', N'America/Santo_Domingo', N'America/Sao_Paulo', N'America/Scoresbysund', N'America/Shiprock', N'America/Sitka', N'America/St_Barthelemy', N'America/St_Johns', N'America/St_Kitts', N'America/St_Lucia', N'America/St_Thomas', N'America/St_Vincent', N'America/Swift_Current', N'America/Tegucigalpa', N'America/Thule', N'America/Thunder_Bay', N'America/Tijuana', N'America/Toronto', N'America/Tortola', N'America/Vancouver', N'America/Virgin', N'America/Whitehorse', N'America/Winnipeg', N'America/Yakutat', N'America/Yellowknife', N'Antarctica/Casey', N'Antarctica/Davis', N'Antarctica/DumontDUrville', N'Antarctica/Macquarie', N'Antarctica/Mawson', N'Antarctica/McMurdo', N'Antarctica/Palmer', N'Antarctica/Rothera', N'Antarctica/South_Pole', N'Antarctica/Syowa', N'Antarctica/Troll', N'Antarctica/Vostok', N'Arctic/Longyearbyen', N'Asia/Aden', N'Asia/Almaty', N'Asia/Amman', N'Asia/Anadyr', N'Asia/Aqtau', N'Asia/Aqtobe', N'Asia/Ashgabat', N'Asia/Ashkhabad', N'Asia/Atyrau', N'Asia/Baghdad', N'Asia/Bahrain', N'Asia/Baku', N'Asia/Bangkok', N'Asia/Barnaul', N'Asia/Beirut', N'Asia/Bishkek', N'Asia/Brunei', N'Asia/Calcutta', N'Asia/Chita', N'Asia/Choibalsan', N'Asia/Chongqing', N'Asia/Chungking', N'Asia/Colombo', N'Asia/Dacca', N'Asia/Damascus', N'Asia/Dhaka', N'Asia/Dili', N'Asia/Dubai', N'Asia/Dushanbe', N'Asia/Famagusta', N'Asia/Gaza', N'Asia/Harbin', N'Asia/Hebron', N'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh', N'Asia/Hong_Kong', N'Asia/Hovd', N'Asia/Irkutsk', N'Asia/Istanbul', N'Asia/Jakarta', N'Asia/Jayapura', N'Asia/Jerusalem', N'Asia/Kabul', N'Asia/Kamchatka', N'Asia/Karachi', N'Asia/Kashgar', N'Asia/Kathmandu', N'Asia/Katmandu', N'Asia/Khandyga', N'Asia/Kolkata', N'Asia/Krasnoyarsk', N'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur', N'Asia/Kuching', N'Asia/Kuwait', N'Asia/Macao', N'Asia/Macau', N'Asia/Magadan', N'Asia/Makassar', N'Asia/Manila', N'Asia/Muscat', N'Asia/Nicosia', N'Asia/Novokuznetsk', N'Asia/Novosibirsk', N'Asia/Omsk', N'Asia/Oral', N'Asia/Phnom_Penh', N'Asia/Pontianak', N'Asia/Pyongyang', N'Asia/Qatar', N'Asia/Qyzylorda', N'Asia/Rangoon', N'Asia/Riyadh', N'Asia/Saigon', N'Asia/Sakhalin', N'Asia/Samarkand', N'Asia/Seoul', N'Asia/Shanghai', N'Asia/Singapore', N'Asia/Srednekolymsk', N'Asia/Taipei', N'Asia/Tashkent', N'Asia/Tbilisi', N'Asia/Tehran', N'Asia/Tel_Aviv', N'Asia/Thimbu', N'Asia/Thimphu', N'Asia/Tokyo', N'Asia/Tomsk', N'Asia/Ujung_Pandang', N'Asia/Ulaanbaatar', N'Asia/Ulan_Bator', N'Asia/Urumqi', N'Asia/Ust-Nera', N'Asia/Vientiane', N'Asia/Vladivostok', N'Asia/Yakutsk', N'Asia/Yangon', N'Asia/Yekaterinburg', N'Asia/Yerevan', N'Atlantic/Azores', N'Atlantic/Bermuda', N'Atlantic/Canary', N'Atlantic/Cape_Verde', N'Atlantic/Faeroe', N'Atlantic/Faroe', N'Atlantic/Jan_Mayen', N'Atlantic/Madeira', N'Atlantic/Reykjavik', N'Atlantic/South_Georgia', N'Atlantic/St_Helena', N'Atlantic/Stanley', N'Australia/ACT', N'Australia/Adelaide', N'Australia/Brisbane', N'Australia/Broken_Hill', N'Australia/Canberra', N'Australia/Currie', N'Australia/Darwin', N'Australia/Eucla', N'Australia/Hobart', N'Australia/LHI', N'Australia/Lindeman', N'Australia/Lord_Howe', N'Australia/Melbourne', N'Australia/NSW', N'Australia/North', N'Australia/Perth', N'Australia/Queensland', N'Australia/South', N'Australia/Sydney', N'Australia/Tasmania', N'Australia/Victoria', N'Australia/West', N'Australia/Yancowinna', N'Brazil/Acre', N'Brazil/DeNoronha', N'Brazil/East', N'Brazil/West', N'CET', N'CST6CDT', N'Canada/Atlantic', N'Canada/Central', N'Canada/Eastern', N'Canada/Mountain', N'Canada/Newfoundland', N'Canada/Pacific', N'Canada/Saskatchewan', N'Canada/Yukon', N'Chile/Continental', N'Chile/EasterIsland', N'Cuba', N'EET', N'EST', N'EST5EDT', N'Egypt', N'Eire', N'Etc/GMT', N'Etc/GMT+0', N'Etc/GMT+1', N'Etc/GMT+10', N'Etc/GMT+11', N'Etc/GMT+12', N'Etc/GMT+2', N'Etc/GMT+3', N'Etc/GMT+4', N'Etc/GMT+5', N'Etc/GMT+6', N'Etc/GMT+7', N'Etc/GMT+8', N'Etc/GMT+9', N'Etc/GMT-0', N'Etc/GMT-1', N'Etc/GMT-10', N'Etc/GMT-11', N'Etc/GMT-12', N'Etc/GMT-13', N'Etc/GMT-14', N'Etc/GMT-2', N'Etc/GMT-3', N'Etc/GMT-4', N'Etc/GMT-5', N'Etc/GMT-6', N'Etc/GMT-7', N'Etc/GMT-8', N'Etc/GMT-9', N'Etc/GMT0', N'Etc/Greenwich', N'Etc/UCT', N'Etc/UTC', N'Etc/Universal', N'Etc/Zulu', N'Europe/Amsterdam', N'Europe/Andorra', N'Europe/Astrakhan', N'Europe/Athens', N'Europe/Belfast', N'Europe/Belgrade', N'Europe/Berlin', N'Europe/Bratislava', N'Europe/Brussels', N'Europe/Bucharest', N'Europe/Budapest', N'Europe/Busingen', N'Europe/Chisinau', N'Europe/Copenhagen', N'Europe/Dublin', N'Europe/Gibraltar', N'Europe/Guernsey', N'Europe/Helsinki', N'Europe/Isle_of_Man', N'Europe/Istanbul', N'Europe/Jersey', N'Europe/Kaliningrad', N'Europe/Kiev', N'Europe/Kirov', N'Europe/Lisbon', N'Europe/Ljubljana', N'Europe/London', N'Europe/Luxembourg', N'Europe/Madrid', N'Europe/Malta', N'Europe/Mariehamn', N'Europe/Minsk', N'Europe/Monaco', N'Europe/Moscow', N'Europe/Nicosia', N'Europe/Oslo', N'Europe/Paris', N'Europe/Podgorica', N'Europe/Prague', N'Europe/Riga', N'Europe/Rome', N'Europe/Samara', N'Europe/San_Marino', N'Europe/Sarajevo', N'Europe/Saratov', N'Europe/Simferopol', N'Europe/Skopje', N'Europe/Sofia', N'Europe/Stockholm', N'Europe/Tallinn', N'Europe/Tirane', N'Europe/Tiraspol', N'Europe/Ulyanovsk', N'Europe/Uzhgorod', N'Europe/Vaduz', N'Europe/Vatican', N'Europe/Vienna', N'Europe/Vilnius', N'Europe/Volgograd', N'Europe/Warsaw', N'Europe/Zagreb', N'Europe/Zaporozhye', N'Europe/Zurich', N'GB', N'GB-Eire', N'GMT', N'GMT+0', N'GMT-0', N'GMT0', N'Greenwich', N'HST', N'Hongkong', N'Iceland', N'Indian/Antananarivo', N'Indian/Chagos', N'Indian/Christmas', N'Indian/Cocos', N'Indian/Comoro', N'Indian/Kerguelen', N'Indian/Mahe', N'Indian/Maldives', N'Indian/Mauritius', N'Indian/Mayotte', N'Indian/Reunion', N'Iran', N'Israel', N'Jamaica', N'Japan', N'Kwajalein', N'Libya', N'MET', N'MST', N'MST7MDT', N'Mexico/BajaNorte', N'Mexico/BajaSur', N'Mexico/General', N'NZ', N'NZ-CHAT', N'Navajo', N'PRC', N'PST8PDT', N'Pacific/Apia', N'Pacific/Auckland', N'Pacific/Bougainville', N'Pacific/Chatham', N'Pacific/Chuuk', N'Pacific/Easter', N'Pacific/Efate', N'Pacific/Enderbury', N'Pacific/Fakaofo', N'Pacific/Fiji', N'Pacific/Funafuti', N'Pacific/Galapagos', N'Pacific/Gambier', N'Pacific/Guadalcanal', N'Pacific/Guam', N'Pacific/Honolulu', N'Pacific/Johnston', N'Pacific/Kiritimati', N'Pacific/Kosrae', N'Pacific/Kwajalein', N'Pacific/Majuro', N'Pacific/Marquesas', N'Pacific/Midway', N'Pacific/Nauru', N'Pacific/Niue', N'Pacific/Norfolk', N'Pacific/Noumea', N'Pacific/Pago_Pago', N'Pacific/Palau', N'Pacific/Pitcairn', N'Pacific/Pohnpei', N'Pacific/Ponape', N'Pacific/Port_Moresby', N'Pacific/Rarotonga', N'Pacific/Saipan', N'Pacific/Samoa', N'Pacific/Tahiti', N'Pacific/Tarawa', N'Pacific/Tongatapu', N'Pacific/Truk', N'Pacific/Wake', N'Pacific/Wallis', N'Pacific/Yap', N'Poland', N'Portugal', N'ROC', N'ROK', N'Singapore', N'Turkey', N'UCT', N'US/Alaska', N'US/Aleutian', N'US/Arizona', N'US/Central', N'US/East-Indiana', N'US/Eastern', N'US/Hawaii', N'US/Indiana-Starke', N'US/Michigan', N'US/Mountain', N'US/Pacific', N'US/Pacific-New', N'US/Samoa', N'UTC', N'Universal', N'W-SU', N'WET', N'Zulu')), [clipTemplateId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL, [shopId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL, [createdAt] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL, [updatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([id]), FOREIGN KEY ([clipTemplateId]) REFERENCES [ClipTemplate] ([id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION, FOREIGN KEY ([shopId]) REFERENCES [Shop] ([id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION);
```

Same format as the other queries, except it's got a list of timezones. I can see the previous queries in the audit log, but not this one.

I've run `SELECT OBJECT_ID('[Client]', 'U')` and it returns `1218103380`, so the query shouldn't actually be doing anything, given the `IF` at the top?

Reproducable every time against multiple Azure SQL databases in different development environments with the node app. Other SQL clients send the query with success. App last worked yesterday. No app or infra changes since.

When putting the query into some online SQL validators like https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/, it says the query is invalid, but MS SQL Server Management Studio thinks it's fine, and I can run it without issue.

Sequelize Config:

```
    database: {
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        dialect: "mssql",
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        loggingEnabled: false,
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        pool: {
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 30000,
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
        },
        port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10) || 1433,
        transactionTimeout: parseInt(process.env.DB_TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT, 10) || 30000,
        username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    }
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Downgrading node from v10 to v8 did the magic for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems 10.17.0 broke my DB connection for long queries. Rolling back to Node v10.16.3 has resolved the issue.

On start up, my Node program was pulling the latest 10.x version. It started using Node v10.17.0, released 21st October 2019, which was when the issue started.

Comment: you can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for timeout error while running long queries.

[connection timeout or already too many clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947066/error-sorry-too-many-clients-already/58518350#58518350)